# SpotifyAPI-NET Giving 'invalid_grant' When Authorizing

Tags: c#, asp.net, aws-lambda, spotify

I'm trying to set up an application using C# on AWS Lambda for the backend, and a React frontend (Currently just a basic locally hosted server).

From the front-end, I begin the OAuth process of requesting an access code from Spotify, then when I have that code I call my backend `server.com/api/authenticate?code=SPOTIFYCODE`
My backend will then attempt to use the clientID, clientSecret and the code passed in from the frontend to retrieve an access token from Spotify.

I would like to use the SpotifyAPI-NET sdk since that does a lot of the hard work, however it always seems to throw a SpotifyAPI.Web.APIException error with `invalid_grant`. I would normally assume the request parameters were wrong, but it works fine making the request manually so I'm stumped.

I can successfully grab an access token with the following:

```cs
// GET api/authenticate
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Authenticate(string code)
{        
    // Exchange the authorization code for an access token
    var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "grant_type", "authorization_code" },
        { "code", code },
        { "redirect_uri", RedirectUri },
        { "client_id", ClientId },
        { "client_secret", ClientSecret }
    };

    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
    var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync(TokenEndpoint, content);
    
    if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) return BadRequest("Failed to get access token.");
    
    var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var tokenResponse = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TokenResponse>(responseContent);
    
    var accessToken = tokenResponse?.AccessToken;

    // Create a new cookie with the access token
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken)) return BadRequest("Failed to get access token. Access token is null or empty.");

    var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
    {
        HttpOnly = true,
        Secure = true, 
        Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1),
        SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
        Domain = Request.Host.Value,
        Path = "/api",
    };
    Response.Cookies.Append("access_token", accessToken, cookieOptions);

    return Ok();
}
```

However if I try to use the same information, but using the sdk following [these instructions](https://johnnycrazy.github.io/SpotifyAPI-NET/docs/authorization_code)... It fails.

````cs
// GET api/authenticate
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> Authenticate(string code)
{    
    var response = await new OAuthClient().RequestToken(
        new AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
            ClientId,
            ClientSecret,
            code,
            new Uri(RedirectUri))
    );

    var accessToken = response.AccessToken;

    // Create a new cookie with the access token
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken)) return BadRequest("Failed to get access token. Access token is null or empty.");

    var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
    {
        HttpOnly = true,
        Secure = true, 
        Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(1),
        SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
        Domain = Request.Host.Value,
        Path = "/api",
    };
    Response.Cookies.Append("access_token", accessToken, cookieOptions);

    return Ok();
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is due to redirect_uri. In your working code, you pass a string but it turns Uri class when you use the SDK.

In the source code of the SDK it converts it to string in this line:

```
new KeyValuePair<string?, string?>("redirect_uri", request.RedirectUri.ToString())
```

And when you do this with a base url, it appends a trailing slash in the end. If your original redirect_uri does not contain trailing slash, then they might mismatch and you get this error.

You can add a trailing slash to your original redirect_uri (when you redirect user to spotify service) to test this case.